# One element with hover, targets multiple element with one CSS animation each

Tags: css, animation, transition

So I am trying to hover on one div and animate three divs  at the same time. 
The div I am trying to animate is:

- the div it self the one im hovering on
- and two children divs inside of it

So my question is how i get the syntax correct. I had it once but then i made some change and now I cant seem to figure it out. just to mention this is all running in sass.

**This is the HTML:**

```
<div id="arrow-container">
    <div id="arrowLine" class="cta-arrow"></div>
    <div id="arrowHead" class="cta-arrow"></div>
</div>
```

**this is style.scss :**

```
#arrow-container{
    width: auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    cursor: pointer;
    #arrowLine{
        background-color: $white;
        width: 2px;
        height: 340px;
    }
    #arrowHead{
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        border-bottom: 2px solid $white;
        border-left: 2px solid $white;
        transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(-24px) translateX(24px);
    }
}
```

**this is the SCSS _animation.scss :**

```
#arrow-container {
    transition: .05s ease-in-out;
} 
#arrow-container:hover {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
----------
#arrowLine {
    transition: .05s ease-in-out;
}
#arrow-container:hover>#arrowLine {
    background-color: #E63946;
}
----------
#arrowHead {
    transition: .05s ease-in-out;
}
#arrow-container:hover>#arrowHead {
    border-color: #E63946;
}
```

and many thanks !

Comment: I'd help if you posted the corresponding HTML too.... :)

Comment: That appears to be ok as it stands. Can you share your html markup? Also, any layout rules for these elements (height/width/position/etc).

Comment: The reasons I can think that your CSS selectors might not work are: 1) #arrowHead and #arrowLine are not immediate descendants of #arrow-container 2) The starting border colors are the same as the colors in the hover state, so there is nothing to animate. Also I assume the dashed lines are not in your actual stylesheet, they are just to make it easier for us to read, yeah?

Comment: I have added all the elements and yes the dashed border is just for you  (: